# how to pass values from ajax to controller on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is my js code which is executed on button click

```
    $("#search_tutor").click(function(){
    $("#show_tutors").hide();
    var subject = $( ".subject" ).val();
    var degree_level = $(".degree_level").val();
    var city = $(".city").val();
    console.log(subject);
    console.log(degree_level);
    console.log(city);
      $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>public_controller/search_tutor_jquery",
      method:"post",
      data:{subject: subject, degree_level : degree_level, city : city},
      success:function(data){
        $('#search_results').html(data);

      }
    });

    });
```

and this is controller function

```
        public function search_tutor_jquery(){
  $subject = strtolower($this->input->post('subject'));
  $degree_level = strtolower($this->input->post('degree_level'));
  $city = strtolower($this->input->post('city'));
  echo $subject; //prints nothing
  $data['filtered_tutors'] = $this->public_model->search($subject,$degree_level,$city);
  $this->load->view('public/search_results',$data);
}
```

values are being logged in console but i cannot receive values in controller. can somebody help me out? 
thanks in advance

Comment: anything in the browser console that indicates an error?

Comment: there is no error. values are logged successfully on console. just cannot receive in controller

Comment: any errors in the server logs

Comment: no errors.. apart form undefined index

Comment: you use jQuery, right? you didn't tag it! Anyway add `dataType: 'json'` and if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0. prefer `type: 'POST'`instead of method. That's in your `$.ajax()` function. Read [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by

```
$('#search_results').load("<?php echo base_url('public_controller/search_tutor_jquery') ?>");
```

Try

```
$('#search_results').html(data);
```

Read about `load()` function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp). It sends a new empty request and load that data to your element. It doesn't load the response.

Comment: i have tried. main problem is that data is not being sent to the controller.

Comment: i m showing data with this method and it is working great.

Comment: i m having issue in sending data to the controller function.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $subject;` ?. If this performs correctly, posting the model code and view code may useful.

Comment: i'm doing echo %_POST['subject'] and it's showing nothing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$_POST['subject']
```

instead of

```
$this->input->post('subject')
```

?

Comment: it gives undefined index.

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: subject

Filename: controllers/Public_controller.php

Comment: oops i meant $_POST['subject'] haha

Comment: Try:
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$subject = $data['subject'];

Comment: yes i've tried this now after you suggested but couldn't get value in controller. i'm printing by print_r($data); but it's showing empty

Comment: the CI function `$this->input->post('subject')`generates `$POST['subject'] ` read [Class Reference, POST](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post)